# Customize primary key field in migration - Laravel 5.3

Tags: primary-key, laravel-5.3

In migration, if we want to add a primary key on table, we use

```
$table->increments('id');
```

This will create an **id** field with **int(10)**

But I don't found any way to customize the primary key. Like what if I want primary key with string type or int with size 5 etc...

BTW, I want the primary key of tiny type. How can I achieve that using migration?

Thanks,
Parth Vora

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize Primary Key by using `primary` method as:

```
$table->tinyInteger('pk');

$table->primary('pk');
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#indexes)

Answer (score 2):

`$table->increments('id');` this statement is just telling that you are auto increment `id` field , if you didn't explicitly define primary key it automatically consider `id` field as a primary key, you can define like this.

`$table->primary('table_id');`

as per [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#indexes)

Hope this will help.

Comment: if you want to auto increment you have to do something like this,
`$table->tinyInteger('table_id')->unsigned()->autoIncrement();`

Comment: Thanks. Laravel has one of the best documentation I have ever seen, but how they forgot to add that method in here. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations